# Is it possible to express $\sqrt[6]{2}$ as rational combination of $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt[4]{2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-numbers

Is it possible to express $\sqrt[6]{2}$ as rational combination of $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt[4]{2}$?

So can we find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt[6]{2}=a+ b\sqrt{2}+c \sqrt[4]{2}$?

My guess is no and one should try to prove by contradiction. And the contradiction should show that either at least one number from ${a, b, c}$ is irrational or at least one number from ${\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[4]{2}}$ is rational.

However, my attempts failed because they lead to some unmanageable (for me at least) long computations.

Can you please prove some smart way to handle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is question about field extensions of the rational numbers. Are you familiar with this subject?

Comment: Yes, but I need elementary proof for that or at least scheme of the proof.

Comment: If you could, then you could double te cube with an unmarked sraightedge and compasses.  Uhhh... no.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I hope this problem is simpler since we are much more limited compared with sraightedge and compasses constructions.

Comment: Raise everything to the sixth power; then the right hand side is a ${\mathbb Q}$-linear combination of the powers of $\sqrt[4]{2}$.

Comment: Just a random thought: would $(x^6-2)(x^4-2)(x^2-2)=0$ and its roots be helpful?

Comment: You could prove using linear algebra and Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: Why was [elementary-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-number-theory) removed? I can see why [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), and I don't know about [irrational-numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrational-numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Eisenstein's Criterion, you know that $x^6-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Observe that $\sqrt[6]{2}$ is a root of this polynomial.

Suppose (for contradiction) that $\sqrt[6]{2}=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt[4]{2}$ for some rational $a$, $b$, and $c$.  Let $y=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt[4]{2}$.  If you look at $y^0,\cdots,y^4$ as vectors in the span of $1$, $\sqrt[4]{2}$, $\sqrt{2}$, and $\sqrt[4]{8}$, then this is a collection of $5$ vectors in a vector space of dimension at most $4$, so there is some nontrivial combination of these which equals zero.  This tells you that there is a *nonzero* polynomial $p$ of degree at most $4$ with rational coefficients with $y$ as a root (since $y^0,\dots,y^4$ is a linear dependent set).

Therefore, $\sqrt[6]{2}$ is a root of both $x^6-2$ and $p$, so it is a root of their gcd (which cannot be $1$ because the gcd needs a root).  This, however, is impossible because such a gcd would need to be of degree at most $4$ and at least $1$ and divide $x^6-2$, but $x^6-2$ is irreducible.  This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is more delicate than it looks, so I have to check everything carefully.

Comment: Yes, I understand the proof now, it is terrific!

Comment: The proof by @robjohn is quite slick and it's worth taking the time to understand it as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** By [Eisenstein's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), $x^{12}-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, there are no $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $ax^6+bx^3+cx^2+d=0$ where $x=2^{1/12}$.